# Mongoose does not remove a document from the database

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Have a small/big problem.

I am trying to remove a document from a Mongoose database, but instead nothing happens.

**Maybe someone has any suggestions?**

**This is my code from the NodeJS application:**

```
router.delete('/delete/:id',(req , res) =>{

  Message.remove({"content": req.params.id}), function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    res.redirect('/getMessages');

  };

 });
```

**And this is my Jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.deleteUser').on('click', deleteUser);
}
);

function deleteUser()
{
    var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure want to delete this message?');

    if (confirmation) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/delete/'+$(this).data('id')

        }).done(function(response){

            window.location.replace('getMessages');
        });
        window.location.replace('getMessages');
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: why are you redirecting in the node.js function?, any console errors?

Comment: why are you doing ajax if you are redirecting after it?

Comment: Console just writes: DELETE /delete/content- - ms - -

Comment: what console ? the node or the browser?

Comment: I mean in the terminal. Browser does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misplaced the callback.

```
Message.remove({"content": req.params.id}), function(err, result){
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }    
   res.redirect('/getMessages');    
};
```

Here the callback should be inside the parenthesis not outside.

I ran the following code with "id" as a parameter and my record was removed. Hope you'r **:id** contains the data that is in your content field not the **Id**.

```
 // Index.js
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="deleteMessage" value="585bc7a2d1387569d13c304a">Delete</button>

 //sample.js
(function(){
    $('#deleteMessage').on("click",function(){           
         $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/delete/'+$(this).val()

        }).done(function(response){
            console.log(response);            
        }).fail(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });           
    });
})();
```

Here is the route for delete :

```
router.delete('/delete/:id',function(req,res,next){      
  Message.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err,response){        
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }    
    res.send(response);
  });

});
```

Comment: I never thought that callback make such a huge impact, I was trying Model.remove({id: product.id}) and other stuff since an hour without success. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't redirect the page on the server side return something to the ajax:

```
router.delete('/delete/:id',(req , res) =>{

  Message.remove({"content": req.params.id}), function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    res.json({status:'ok'});
    //res.send(JSON.stringify({status:'ok'}));

  };

 });
```

Comment: I changed to what you wrote, however, still nothing ):

Comment: any console errors? is your ajax successful?why are you redirecting after ajax?

Comment: I think my Ajax is successful since i receive the correct content i need to. Console just writes: DELETE /delete/content- - ms - -

Comment: your page should redirect after ajax

Comment: I have a schema for Message and it has a field called 'content'. And thats what i am trying to catch and using it to remove the document from the database.

Comment: No, it is not. Thats the problem. Nothing changes. Nothing is deleted.

Comment: this means your ajax is not triggering correctly , any console errors in the browser, what status code does the xhr request got?

Comment: answer my question and i will tell you

Comment: if you have a url even better

Comment: There are no errors in the browser (: And you have my Ajax cod (:

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your xhr request?

Comment: What is xhr request?  I am new to node (:

Comment: its the ajax request man you new to javascript it seems , go to the network tab trigger the ajax and the xhr request will appear there make a screenshot of the headers by selecting the xhr request

Comment: i sad to screenshot the headers not the xhr body

Comment: it should look something like http://docs.pyspider.org/en/latest/imgs/request-headers.png